# find common elements in the strings python

Tags: python

I'm trying to find common elements in the strings reading from a file. And this is what I wrote:

```
file = open ("words.txt", 'r')

while 1:
    line = file.readlines()
    if len(line) == 0:
        break
    print line
file.close


def com_Letters(*strings):
    return set.intersection(*map(set,strings))
```

and the result turns out: `['out\n', 'dog\n', 'pingo\n', 'coconut']`

I put `com_Letters(line)`, but the result is empty.

Comment: hey, what's in `words.txt`?  also, what output are you expecting?

Comment: What is that loop supposed to be doing? [`readlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines) is guaranteed to read until EOF. Were you trying to guard against something impossible, or is there some other reason for it?

Comment: When I run this, no matter what's in the file, I actually get `TypeError: descriptor 'intersection' of 'set' object needs an argument`, not an empty result.

Comment: More generally, please read [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), and then give us a complete example, with runnable code, input, expected and actual output, etc. Just showing a sample of code and then trying to describe what happened when you made some vaguely-specified change makes it very hard to debug your code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems, but neither one is with `com_Letters`.

First, this code guarantees that `line` will always be an empty list:

```
while 1:
    line = file.readlines()
    if len(line) == 0:
        break
    print line
```

The first time through the loop, you call [`readlines()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines), which will

> Read until EOF using readline() and return a list containing the lines thus read.

If the file is empty, that's an empty list, so you'll break.

Otherwise, you'll print out the list, and go back into the loop. At which point `readlines()` is going to have nothing left to read, since you already read until EOF, so it's guaranteed to be an empty list. Which means you'll break.

Either way, `list` ends up empty.

It's not clear what you're trying to do with that loop. There's never any good reason to call `readlines()` repeatedly on the same file. But, even if there were, you'd probably want to accumulate all of the results, rather than just keeping the last (guaranteed-empty) result. Something like this:

```
while 1:
    new_line = file.readlines()
    if len(new_line) == 0:
        break
    print new_line
    line += new_line
```

---

Anyway, if you fix that problem (e.g., by scrapping the whole loop and just using `line = file.readlines()`), you're calling `com_Letters` with a single list of strings. That's not particularly useful; it's just a very convoluted way of calling `set`. If it's not clear why:

- Since there's only one argument (a list of strings), `*strings` ends up as a one-element tuple of that argument.
- `map(set, strings)` on a single-element tuple just calls `set` on that element and returns a single-element list.
- `*map(set, strings)` explodes that into one argument, the set.
- `set.intersection(s)` is the same thing as `s.intersection()`, which just returns `s` itself.

---

All of this would be easier to see if you broke up some of those complex expressions and `print`ed the intermediate values. Then you'd know exactly where it first goes wrong, instead of just knowing it's somewhere in a long chain of events.

---

A few side notes:

You forgot the `()` on the `file.close`, which means you're not actually closing the file. One of the many reasons that `with` is better is that it means you can't make that mistake.

Use plural names for collections. `line` sounds like a variable that should have a single line in it, not a variable that should have all of your lines.

The `readlines` function with no sizehint argument is basically useless. If you're just going to iterate over the lines, you can do that to the file itself. If you really need the lines in a list instead of reading them lazily, `list(file)` makes your intention clearer—and doesn't mislead you into thinking it might be useful to do repeatedly.

The Pythonic way to check for an empty collection is just `if not line:`, rather than `if len(line) == 0:`.

`while True` is clearer than `while 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest modifying the function as follows:

```
def com_Letters(strings):
    return set.intersection(*map(set,strings))
```

I think the function is treating the argument strings as a list of a list of strings (only one argument passed in this case a single list) and therefore not finding the intersection.